# CakePHP Bake templates controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cake-bake

I'm creating a custom bake template and I'd like to fetch DB table column type, and comments on a controller file location: **Template\Bake\Element\Controller\index.twig**, when I'm using code `{% set fields = Bake.filterFields(fields, schema, modelObj) %}` which I've found on a file **Template\Bake\Element\form.twig**, it is returning errors showing fields, schema are NULL.

Can someone please assist how I can fetch DB table column type, and comments on a controller file? Since I want to add a FIELDS ARRAY in a recordSet generated by Bake command.

CakePHP v3.8.2 and Bake v1.x

Thanks.

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `Controller` command doesn't set the schema or its columns for the view, you'd have to obtain that on your own via the table object (`modelObj`), either inside of your template:

```php
{% set schema = modelObj.getSchema() %}
{% set fields = schema.columns() %}
{% set fields = Bake.filterFields(fields, schema, modelObj) %}
```

or by using an event listener for the `Bake.beforeRender.Controller.controller` event, which is being dispatched before a controller template is being rendered, and will allow you access to the view and its variables:

```php
// in config/bootstrap_cli.php

use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Event\EventManager;

EventManager::instance()->on(
    'Bake.beforeRender.Controller.controller',
    function (Event $event) {
        /** @var \Cake\View\View $view */
        $view = $event->getSubject();

        /** @var \Cake\ORM\Table $table */
        $table = $view->get('modelObj');

        $schema = $table->getSchema();
        $fields = $schema->columns();

        $view->set(compact('schema', 'fields'));
    }
);
```

See also

- **[Bake Cookbook > Extending Bake](https://book.cakephp.org/bake/1/en/development.html)**